# Winsock 2.0 Will Not Connect to Public IP Address

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, ip-address, winsock2

So I am trying to build a simple text IM program to get into the wonderful world of networking. I have written 2 programs using Winsock 2.0 with C++: a server and a client. I have specified a UDP connection via the socket creation:

```
SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

Everything works when I try to connect to the server using my local IP address. However, It will not connect when I use my internet IP address. I am fairly certain that it is NOT a firewall issue, because I did multiple tests with both my firewall and antivirus disabled. Is there something I am missing? Can you think of any other reasons why it would be able to connect via the local address, but not the public IP address? Thank you very much!

Comment: Port forwarding on your router and all the routers until you reach the public domain is done properly ?

Comment: Hmmmm...That's probably it then. I have not done anything with port forwarding. I'm running everything through port 17000 in the code. I have never done this before; what does it mean to forward ports, and how do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Port forwarding redirects port traffic, visit the link that Steve-o has posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the public IP address you have is owned by your network router appliance.  It needs to be configured to pass traffic onto your computer

```
  public IP            internal router
   address +--------+  IP address  +---------+
      v    |        |  v           |         |
 ----------+ router +--------------+ desktop +
           |        |           ^  |         |
           +--------+   internal   +---------+
                      desktop IP address
```

http://portforward.com/

Comment: You mean my router needs to be configured to pass traffic onto my computer? Is this what port forwarding does? 

If I forward port 17000, does that mean I am telling my router to send to my computer any information that comes in to port 17000?

Comment: @Jeremy That is correct, the link provides some documentation for common devices.  "Traffic on port 123 must be sent to internal IP 192.168.1.3 on port 123" for example.

Comment: So why is port forwarding usually not required, but in this case it is? Does it have something to do with me hardcoding port 17000?

Comment: @Jeremy because home users behind NAT don't usually host servers, they're usually client end-users only.  Read [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) (or [NAT-PMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol) for OSX) for methods around this problem.

Comment: I am sure that I have successfully forwarded port 17000 to my computer, however, my client will still not connect to the server through the public IP address. Can you think of anything else that I missed? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jeremy install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see what is happening on the network.

Comment: This is alot to take in at once, but I got wireshark installed, and I am monitoring packets running to and from my computer. I can see all of the outgoing packets being sent from my client that tried to my public IP address. It looks like the problem is that they are being sent to port 26690 instead of 17000. I use the sendto command:

`sendto(Socket, SendBuffer, 1, 0, (sockaddr*)&ServerAddress, sizeof(sockaddr));`

where:

`ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(<string for public ip>);
ServerAddress.sin_port = 17000;`

Comment: @Steve-o let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2879/discussion-between-jeremy-and-steve-o)